# EXCEL: Update cell to default value when list option already selected

Tags: excel

I'm an intermediate excel user at best and need help please!

I want to update a cell to a default value when a condition is no longer met. The updated cell must override the preexisting value from a drop menu

[Example of change needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMDUa.png)

Was attempting the following in C2:
`=if(A2=B2,DropMenu,"INCOMPLETE")`
*DropMenu is a named list*

Which works fine as long as cell C2 is empty.
I need it to work if C2 already has a value.

Please help

Comment: Welcome to SO. You cannot have a formula and a value at the same time in a cell. For this you'll need to code something in VBA.

Comment: Thanks so much, do you possibly have some VBA code that i can manipulate to achieve this